# Number of documents inside a document library will be different when viewed from "Site Content" & "Open with Explorer"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, administration

I have a document library inside my modern communication team site. Now from "Site Content" the document library has 6802 items as follow:-

[image]

Now I went to the document library using classic interface >> under "Library" tab >> I click on "Open with explorer", as follow:-

[image]

I was able to access the library inside my pc. But when I right click on the document library folder >> "Properties" >> I got that the docuemnt library contains  only 6332 items (5471 + 861), as follow:-

[image]

So what is the reason for this differences? And which number is the accurate one?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is because, site contents shows count of all the documents and folders, but when you open document library it shows only documents and folders which you have permission to access.

Also there might be some documents which are first time uploaded and not checked in. This documents will also be not visible to you.

For referenece: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bde7e1db-9720-4774-ab02-307c23438613/view-all-site-content-showing-the-wrong-number-of-items?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Comment: @P S thanks for the reply. now i do not have any document that is checked-out + i am login using the site collection admin, which is also the global admin for office 365,, so i do not think this is a permission issue... at the end we are talking about 500 items differences...

Comment: first time uploaded and not checked in files will be not visible even if you are admin. To check that you can go to Document library settings and then 'Manage files which have no checked in version'. For more info refer http://www.benprins.net/2015/01/14/sharepoint-show-all-files-which-have-no-checked-in-version/

Comment: @P S thanks for the reply.. actually when i go to this location i will get this message "All files currently have a checked in version." .. so i do not have any checked-out items...

Answer (score 2):

Because there are hidden files when you open the document library with explorer.
You could select “Hidden items” in the view to show the hidden files when you open the document library with explorer.

[image]

But when you see the document library from "Site Content", it will only show the number of the items in the document library.

Updated:

Yes, you are right.

When you create a new document library, then in the site content it will shows 0. But when you open the document library with windows explorer, it will show the count of the files.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply... now i already have "showing hidden items" enabled ,, as when i open the document library with explorer, i can view the "forms" hidden folder... but you are saying hidden contents (file and folder) will not be counted in the explorer count, unlike the sharepoint site collection count?.. but when we create a new document library its site content count will be 0 , even there will be a hidden "Forms" folder.. is this correct?

Comment: I have updated the reply.